# There is anyway to try catch image, svg load from Url in Fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

I want to add an svg image from a url, it gives me an error when I try to add it to the canvas. I want to catch the error to notify the user of the error. However fabricjs throws this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloneNode')
    at fabric.min.js:1:43771
    at y.parseSVGDocument (fabric.min.js:1:44470)
    at onComplete (fabric.min.js:1:49688)
    at s.onreadystatechange (fabric.min.js:1:31687)
(anonymous) @ fabric.min.js:1
y.parseSVGDocument @ fabric.min.js:1
onComplete @ fabric.min.js:1
s.onreadystatechange @ fabric.min.js:1
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
fabric.util.request @ fabric.min.js:1
loadSVGFromURL @ fabric.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.html:48
```

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to do this too, but I think the error thrown is too far down in fabric source, so that it is still returning successfully even though an error was thrown farther down.  If you really need to verify the loaded image exists, you can do a workaround.

Create an invisible canvas, and set an arbitrary timeout for each load.  In the callback to load SVG, load the image to the invisible canvas.  When your timeout completes, check if the invisible canvas does in fact have an image, otherwise, show a message to the user.  Then remove the canvas.